# Can chdir() accept relative paths?

Tags: c, linux, chdir

In C on linux, can the chdir() function accept a relative path?

Comment: Why not? There's nothing in the manual that says otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The current working directory is a property of the process.

---

To expand on that a little - here are a couple of the relevant [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) definitions:

- The [current working directory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_439) is defined as "a directory, associated with a process, that is used in pathname resolution for pathnames that do not begin with a slash character" (there is more detail in the section on [pathname resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12)).
- [`chdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html) is defined to set the current working directory to a pathname.

It seems somewhat circular, but there is nothing special about a "pathname" in the context of the argument `chdir()`; it is subject to pathname resolution as normal.