# What is the difference between _chdir and SetCurrentDirectory in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Are there any difference that I should choose one over the other?

Comment: I don't know the answer but +1 for asking.

Comment: You might instead want to compare `SetCurrentDirectory` to `_tchdir`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They achieve the same result but belong to different APIs, so they return their results and report errors in different ways.

If you're already using other routines from either API, pick that one. If not, SetCurrentDirectory() is more "Windowsy", while _chdir() is more similar to the POSIX API. If you have a mind to port the code to, say, a Linux platform, use _chdir(); if you know you will only ever run the code on Windows platforms, SetCurrentDirectory().

Answer (score 6):

`_chdir` actually uses `SetCurrentDirectory` internally, so on most cases they are effectively interchangeable. However, `_chdir` does one more thing: it updates the current directory of the current drive, stored in an environment variable. This is needed, as the remark in `_tchdir` states, because "other functions (fullpath, spawn, etc) need them to be set".

I'm not sure how much this is needed these days, but I would say - if you're using those POSIX-style functions for file operations, path manipulation, process creation etc., use `_chdir` accordingly. If you're using Win32 API functions directly, use `SetCurrentDirectory`.

Comment: Is the is same *fake* per drive current directory that the cmd.exe interpreter uses?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'm not sure I understand your question (could you rephrase it?), but I think the answer is yes - it uses the weird "=C" environment variables, which according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx) are also used by cmd.

Comment: yeah that's what I mean and Raymond explains what I mean by faking

Answer (score 0):

SetCurrentDirectory is a macro that will resolve to SetCurrentDirectoryA or SetCurrentDirectoryW depending on the build settings.  There is no system provided macro for _chdir and _wchdir.

The [MSDN page for SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530.aspx) states that the argument can be relative to the current working directory or absolute.  The documentation for _chdir does not say either way, though it seems that it does [Can chdir() accept relative paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998530/can-chdir-accept-relative-paths) on Linux.