# Setting the current directory of a running app in C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, native

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/885081/655794) gives a solution using C#, I was wondering what the equivalent would be if one were using only c++ (not c++\cli)

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Is there anything in boost that might do the trick?

Based on this problem I've been having: [Correctly creating and running a win32 service with file I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253921/correctly-creating-and-running-a-win32-service-with-file-i-o)

Comment: You want a C runtime API for this ? or a Windows API for this ? CRT = _chdir(), WinAPI = SetCurrentDirectory().

Comment: @CraigNelson: I think eq-'s answer is just fine. All I need now is System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: I concur (and bumped his feedback accordingly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SetCurrentDirectory` (in Win32):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

`current_path` in `boost::filesystem`:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path

The equivalent for BaseDirectory might be `GetModuleFileName` (with a null handle for the first argument), followed by `GetFullPathName` to get the directory from the executable path.

Comment: great answer! but is there an equivelent for the "System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" call? i believe it's the path to the exe being run

Comment: Just as an extra, the POSIX API : `#include <unistd.h> chdir(const char*)`, which shall work on Linux, Mac, BSDs, ... I heard that Windows also implements some POSIX calls. Can some WinApi expert say something about?

Comment: Hmmm... I believe @Anon ymous answered my question.

Comment: Regarding full path to file name, one of the most abused API's in Windows: GetModuleFileName(), will probably get what you want. I'm not familiar with boost (and I think I'm the last C++ engineer in modern times that isn't) but I'm sure there is a property or API buried in there to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WINAPI.

There is one more answer available at [What is the difference between _chdir and SetCurrentDirectory in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544153/what-is-the-difference-between-chdir-and-setcurrentdirectory-in-windows)

Perhaps there is a need for Module Name as well(Seems from comments),Here is one from my old store:-

```
int main()
{
  char path[MAX_PATH]={0};
  GetModuleFileName(0,path,MAX_PATH);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, the complete equivalent of

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory ( System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory )`
```

would be:

```
// Get full executable path
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

// Get executable directory
boost::filesystem::path path(buffer);
path = path.parent_path();

// Set current path to that directory
boost::filesystem::current_path( path );
```

Note that there is no platform-agnostic way to get an application's directory, as C++ doesn't recognize the concept of directories in the standard.  Boost doesn't appear to have an equivalent function either.