# Can `Dir.chdir` change to a relative path?

Tags: ruby, path, dir

`Dir.chdir` can change to an absolute path:

```
Dir.chdir("/var/spool/mail")
```

Can it change to a relative path such as:

```
Dir.chdir("log/spool/mail")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can chdir() accept relative paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998530/can-chdir-accept-relative-paths)

Comment: @Alfabravo, not sure I'd consider that a dupe since it has nothing to do with Ruby per se. Ruby (and any other language) is free to expand (or contract) the functionality of any system calls as it sees fit. For example, `bash` provides `~` as an extension even though `chdir()` knows nothing of it.

Comment: @paxdiablo looks like a wrong call, indeed. Didn't see that one tag and reminded of the other question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html) don't make it very clear, it can certainly do so.

See the following transcript, which first goes to the root directory then uses relative movement to get to `/tmp`:

```
pax$ ruby <<EOF
...>    puts ""
...>    Dir.chdir("/")
...>    puts Dir.pwd
...>    Dir.chdir("tmp")
...>    puts Dir.pwd
...> EOF

/
/tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It will accept relative paths.

```
Dir.chdir("log/spool/mail")
```